# What is the reference for the hadith الله الله في أصحابي?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, uloom-al-hadith

What is the reference and full wording of hadith which praises Sahaaba (May Allah be pleased with all of them) whose wording is approximately sounds like this

> الله الله في أصحابي

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #### الله الله في أصحابي، لا تتخذوهم غرضا بعدي، فمن أحبهم فبحبي أحبهم، ومن أبغضهم فببغضي أبغضهم، ومن آذاهم فقد آذاني، ومن آذاني فقد آذى الله، ومن آذى الله فيوشك أن يأخذه
>
> (Fear) Allah! (Fear) Allah regarding my Companions! Do not make them objects of insults after me. Whoever loves them, it is out of love of me that he loves them. And whoever hates them, it is out of hatred for me that he hates them. And whoever harms them, he has harmed me, and whoever harms me, he has offended Allah, and whoever offends Allah, [then] he shall soon be punished.

Recorded in, for example:

- [Jami` at-Tirmidhi -  المناقب](https://sunnah.com/urn/737500)
- [Musnad Ahmad - مسند البصريين - حديث عبد الله بن مغفل المزني](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13157/20948#p1)
- [Sahih Ibn Hibban - كتاب إخباره صلى الله عليه وسلم عن مناقب الصحابة](https://al-maktaba.org/book/31691/14633#p1)